# How to speed up drawing many circles in Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In python PIL lib, I'm using

```
>>> draw.ellipse((x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r))
```

to draw circle as nodes. However, since there are thousands of nodes to draw, this takes too long.
Is there faster way to draw all my nodes?

For background: to draw a tree-like graph, with circles as nodes.

Comment: What's the rest of your python program? I'll bet there are bigger bottlenecks elsewhere

Comment: Are circles the best way to show locations? Maybe a sqaure? or something else,such as a scaled image and then use the `paste` method to put the scaled circle there.

Comment: for 25k nodes, it cost 6s to draw all nodes.

Comment: Don't confuse 'massive' with 'many'

Comment: Are you sure that this line *is* the actual bottleneck?

Comment: If the circles/ellipses are all the same size, you only need to draw it once and then copy it to all the other locations, which may be faster.

Answer (score 5):

If you draw that many ellipses every cycle it will be slow.

Is there a specific reason you need to use PIL? From your question details, I am not sure PIL is suited for your task: you need a graphics library, not an image manipulation library. There is a difference.

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) is a SDL wrapper suited for high performance drawing routines.

Some tricks include drawing to a [surface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) once, and then only redrawing dirty regions. [A tutorial of this can be found here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html):

> Most people new to graphics programming use the first option - they update the whole screen every frame. The problem is that this is unacceptably slow for most people.
>
> The solution is called 'dirty rect animation'. Instead of updating the whole screen every frame, only the parts that changed since the last frame are updated.

Comment: thanks. i'm using it in SAE(similar to GAE), C src compile is not allowed. it seems a trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I found image.paste() improve speed to about 5 times. there's a transparent problem to avoid overlapping, so mask make speed a little slower.

```
def init_circle(r):
    center = [r] * 2
    im = Image.new(IMG_MODE, [r * 2] * 2, FG_COLOR)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
    draw.setink(BG_COLOR)
    draw.ellipse((1, 1, r * 2 - 1, r * 2 - 1), fill=NODE_COLOR)
    mask = invert(im.convert('L'))
    return im.crop((0, 0) + (r * 2, r * 2)), mask
```

to use it:

```
im.paste(circle, (x, y, x + 2 * r, y + 2 * r), mask=mask)
```

Comment: Good work taking marineau's suggestion. Copy pasting is a good idea.